# How to add flutter image from local folder stored in assets

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have Stored local images in assets/images file added the pubspcs.yml also
assets: 
    - Assets/images/  but i am fetching values from another dummy.dart file like this

```
return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(categoryTitle)),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return MealItem(
              id: displayedMeals[index].id,
              title: displayedMeals[index].title,
              **imageUrl: displayedMeals[index].imageUrl,**
              duration: displayedMeals[index].duration,
              affordability: displayedMeals[index].affordability,
              complexity: displayedMeals[index].complexity,
           // removeItem: _removeMeal,
            );
                /* Text(categoryMeals[index].title) */;
          },
          itemCount: displayedMeals.length,
        )
 );
```

and I want the image to come with this index file which i am fetching from dummy.dart

```
 imageUrl:
        'https://www.whiskaffair.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Hyderabadi-Mutton-Biryani-6.jpg',
```

instead of this i want from the image from `assets/images` folder

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want a placeholder for the image which is fetched from a URL?

Comment: @SanjaySharma I have stored local images in assets/images folder and I am fetching some values with the imageURL from dummy.dart file in the listview..if I give http://...someonlineimage...image is showing...but I want to add image from local folder

Comment: Can you share the code of `MealItem`

Comment: class MealItem extends StatelessWidget { final String imageUrl;  MealItem({  @required this.imageUrl, });

Comment: Are you serious? This is not the complete code of `MealItem` :)

Comment: sorry sanjay this is the code..children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    imageUrl,
                    height: 250,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),

Comment: Replace Image.network with the answer

Comment: In `MealItem` you could replace `Image.network` with `Image.asset` instead. Then use `imageUrl: 'assets/images/image1.jpg'` where you pass url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an asset image as default image.

```dart
 child: new Container(
      child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          placeholder: 'place_holder.jpg',
          image:url
      )
  )
```

Put this in pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
  - assets/place_holder.jpg
```

Comment: Hi sanjay can you give more info if I want to add multiple images from assets/images folder and render it in to assetNetwork... I have more than 100 images

Comment: Add `- assets/img/`  and put all the images inside `img` folder

Answer (score 0):

Images are resolved using [`ImageProvider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html).

There is a bunch of concrete implementations for different sources of images: `FileImage`, `AssetImage`, `NetworkImage`, `MemoryImage`, etc.
Also there is associated factory constructors on `Image` class.

Probably you have something similar in `MealItem`:

```dart
Image.network(imageUrl)
```

You could either use `ImageProvider`:

```dart
Image(image: imageProvider)
```

Or directly provide `Image` widget in constructor.

Anyway you should know the source of the image to use appropriate `ImageProvider` implementation or `Image` constructor.